# Sankaracharya's philosophical 'Sarvagnapeetha' event at Kashmir

Tags: history, advaita

What historically authenticated records of this Adi-Sankarācharya's event exist now ? i.e., before he established Shankara Mutt at KedarNath?

When was it conducted, who were the organizers and participants? How were meeting details recorded?

[Vedanta Sadas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8bB-aaVZv4)
[1:48:48 sec to 1:52:26 sec]

The movie/video script may have been altered for some popular appeal.

Comment: sarvajna peetham at kudajadri mountain kollur

Comment: Near Mookanbika/Karnataka? Any documents survived/available ?

Comment: I am saying that the place is in Karnataka

Comment: So the meeting was to nominate/elect  Shankara as Head of Peetham at Kashmir?

Comment: what did u read ? and which book ?

Comment: No book read. At 1:54:50 in above video  discussed about his suitability and eligibility of the Peetham. Maybe it is cinematic.